# My responsive website doesn't look correct on Mobile devices?

Tags: css, html, mobile, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I've followed a great tutorial for designing a responsive Navigational menu.
When testing the menu on my desktop PC, all looks great. Then as a test, I looked at the website on my mobile - Sony Ericsson Aino (Lame I know) and it looked like the menu couldn't pick up the CSS (style.css). Strange because I've linked my stylesheet properly. I'm not sure if it's my phone but can anyone see what I've done wrong here? Go to www.testing123.co.za .
Problem is that I don't have any tablets, androids or other mobile devices to view the site on, so I don't know if the website (menu) is working on those devices.

Do you need me to copy the CSS in here? Otherwise you can always source code it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Aino uses [NetFront browser](http://www.access-company.com/products/mobile_solutions/netfrontmobile/browser/index.html) 3.5

The CSS/HTML standards that this phone supports are listed here: http://dl-www.sonymobile.com/cws/download/1/708/159/1277364112/DW-88004-dg_web_browser_nf3_r31a.pdf [see page 12]

I suggest you start with some very basic CSS and test, then keep adding to your stylesheet until it doesn't work.

Note: Older NetFront Browsers (below version 3.5) will ignore the rest of the stylesheet after a media query.

On another note, your stylesheet has the media queries listed from largest to smallest. From a mobile-first perspective you should reverse these, so the smallest is first.

Comment: Excellent advice mate! Thanks for the link, I'll certainly look at it!

Answer (score 0):

You're using the HTML5 `nav` element with a XHTML 1.0 DOCTYPE. Change:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Ok, I did that and checked on my phone - it still looks like the navigation menu isn't picking up the css (IE: it looks like I haven't linked style.css). See I don't want to be waisting my time for it to look fine on my mobile, but if it works on popular devices such as blackberry, ipad, androids etc. etc. then I'm happy. I'm basing all this on my stupid phones browser (which isn't a popular phone at all)!

Comment: Strange, I thought that would fix the problem straight away. Unfortunately I don't have a smartphone or tablet to test on either, but I did find this post: http://goo.gl/WOVZ2 . Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ah wicked. Great link! If I could mark your answer as "useful" (1 up), then I would, but my reputation isn't good enough yet, lol!